# Custom Facebook share button is working in all browsers except for Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I'm using this code for my Facebook share button. It works everywhere except for Firefox.

When working properly, a small window pops up with an option to share the given page on Facebook. On Firefox, the window pops up but the original tab opens up "javascript:fbshareCurrentPage()" in the browser, resulting in the page simply saying "false"

I'm working in Bootstrap

Here is the javascript:

```
<script language="javascript">
function fbshareCurrentPage()
{window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
u="+escape(window.location.href)+"&t="+document.title, '', 
'menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,height=300,width=600');
return false; }
</script>
```

And the html:

```
 <a style="background:#337ab7; color:#ffffff;" class="btn btn-social-icon
 btn-facebook" href="javascript:fbshareCurrentPage()"  alt="Share on Facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use void()

```
javascript:void(fbshareCurrentPage())
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void